# Drush and MAMP3: cannot connect to database

Tags: drush

I've just updated to MAMP 3.1, and am running Yosemite 10.10.3 (public beta).  Since updating, I cannot perform any commands using Drush.

I have:

1. sim-linked from /var/mysql and also /var/lib/misql into /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
2. Tested the connection to the database using Sequel pro;
3. Tested the connection using a standard PHP script.

In both 2 and 3 above, I used the direct path to the MAMP socket, and also the one in /var/mysql/mysql.sock

So can anyone think of a reason why this won't work?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for those suggestions.  I inadvertently stumbled on  a solution.  I'm no expert here, so there could (and probably are) reasons why this isn't a good idea but I'll share it anyway.

I simply created a sim-link by doing the following:
cd /tmp
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock mysql.sock

Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

2 things seem to work:

- setting your mysql / pgsql to 127.0.0.1 in your settings.php file instead of localhost (if that was the case)
- reverting to Drush 6

But this is still an issue on MAMP 3.1 + Drush 7 that needs to be resolved.

Comment: Interestingly, I only updated to Drush 7 in the first place because the update to MAMP 3.1 caused my Drush 6 setup to stop working.